# Изменение повторяющихся значений sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с данными, допустим вот так:

```
ID | IMG
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 2
5  | 2
6  | 3
```

Задача стоит в том, что бы изменить все повторяющиеся значение на 0, но при этом оставить самое первое неизменным.

Т.е. в итоге должно получиться вот так:

```
ID | IMG
1  | 1
2  | 0
3  | 2
4  | 0
5  | 0
6  | 3
```

Уже пол дня сижу с этой проблемой и никак не могу понять как составить запрос

Comment: А версия MySQL - какая?

Comment: @Akina 5.7.28 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1 SET
    img = 0
WHERE
    id in (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            _all.id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    MIN(id) as id, img
                FROM
                    t1
                GROUP BY img
            ) as firsts,
            t1 as _all
        WHERE
            _all.img = firsts.img
            AND
            _all.id != firsts.id) as t);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно было проще

```
update t1 set
  img = 0
where id not in
  (select
     min(t1.id)
   from t1
   group by t1.img)
```