# Составить запрос выборки без повторов по одному полю

Tags: sql, oracle

есть таблица (oracle) где колонка Param имеет дублирующие значения - 111

```
Name    Param
АА      111
BB      222
CC      111
DD      333
```

пробую составить запрос что-то типа

`select Name, Param, row_number() over (partition by Name order by Param) from name_param;`

и получить

```
Name    Param
АА      111
BB      222
DD      333
```

без дубликата по полю `Param`

но не совсем получается(

подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121816/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-sql

Comment: В MySQL можно сгруппировать по `Param` и взять, например, минимум по `Name`. Возможно, тут получится так же

Comment: По какому алгоритму для `111` выбрано `AA` и отброшено `CC`?

Comment: А метка [java] здесь зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо решить, что делать с полем `name`. Взять минимальное, максимальное?

Перечисление всех значений в строчку и минимальное значение

```
select
  Param, listagg (name, ';') WITHIN GROUP (name) Names, min(name) MName
from name_param
group by Param
```

Результат

```
Param   Names   MName
111     АА;CC   AA     
222     BB      BB
333     DD      DD
```

На основе вашего запроса, первый в списке (что идентично использованию `min`)

```
select
  Param, name
from 
(select
  param, name, row_number() over (partition by param order by name) num
from name_param)
where num = 1
```